# Start a dynamic route with @

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js, url-routing

In my NextJS application (I use the pages router), I have a file named `@[username].tsx` - similar to YouTube's user profile link - in the `pages` folder. However, visiting `/@lordsarcastic` shows a 404 page. How do I allow `@[username]` format for user profile pages on NextJS using the pages router?

Comment: why dont you want to use [username].tsx and inside add checks that username starts with @?

Comment: That also works. However, I'm avoiding repeating these checks for nested routes too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a client `template.(js|ts)` file to achieve your goal. First you need to create the following structure inside your project.

```bash
app/
├─ [username]/
│  ├─ page.js
│  ├─ template.js
```

We use a template because they are similar to a layout in that it wraps each child layout or page but unlike layouts that maintain state across routes, templates create a new instance for each of their children on navigation. Inside your file template you can then do something like this:

```js
"use client";

import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

// templates are server components by default but do not receive any
// params, henceforth we need to rely on hooks on the client side.
export default function UserTemplate({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();  
  const { username } = useParams();

  if (!username?.startsWith("@")) {
    router.replace("/");
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

This will only render your layout on the client side, and your page, sub-pages and subsequent components inside the page will still be server components because client components can receive server components as children. This setup prevents repeating these checks for nested routes.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I am using pages directory and not the app directory. How can this apply?

Comment: @Lord_Sarcastic Sadly, this is going to be quit a bit harder to replicate in the pages directory.